# Why does loading my Shared Object file give an "Unsatisfied Link" error in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface

I am trying to confirm that I can use JNI to have my Java program call functions from a .so file. I have tried following this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html

I have been able to successfully build my C and Java projects. When I try to run the Java project, I receive this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnidemojava.Main.nativePrint()V

I think it occurs because the .so is not properly linked.

I am running Netbeans 8.2 and Ubuntu 18.04. Please see my IDE and error in the screenshot below:
[image: Java project with unsatisfied link error at runtime]

The C code I am using is:

[image: C code]

Please let me know how I can correct this error.

Comment: You haven't shown us your C code. Also, have you checked that the .so file exists in the path you're using, and that it exports a `Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint` symbol?

Comment: @Michael I uploaded a screen shot of my C code. I also verified that my .so file is at /home/thomas/NetBeansProjects/JNIDemoCdl/dist/  However, I am not sure how I can verify that it exports the symbol mentioned above. Can you suggest how I can do this?

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Post the code as actual text.

Comment: Show the results of `nm libJNIDemoCdl.so | grep nativePrint`, which tests if your library exports that symbol.

Comment: @Botje in the terminal, I moved to the directory in my code where the .so file is, and I entered `nm libJNIDemoCdl.so | grep nativePrint'. The result is '000004cd T Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint'
This appears to show that grep has found nativePrint. If it shows that native print is in the library, and the library is in the correct location, what would cause the unsatisfied link error?

Comment: I'm baffled why it does not work.. Can you run your test code with `-Xcheck:jni -verbose:jni` ?

Comment: @Botje I executed my code from the terminal with:

`java -Xcheck:jni -verbose:jni Main.java`

Result:


`Checked JNI functions are being used to validate JNI usage`

`[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Object.registerNatives ... JNI]`


[...]


`[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes ... JNI]`

`Error: Could not find or load main class Main.java`

`[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Shutdown.halt0 ... JNI]`


As it says, the error is it cannot load the main class from Main.java. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Botje I have read that this error can occur if my classpath is not set up correctly

Comment: Should be `java -Xcheck:jni -verbose:jni -cp . jnidemojava.Main` in your project directory

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer your question directly, but I am pretty sure other comments have given you lots of suggestions already. From my side, maybe you can consider switching to a different build chain: https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU - and here you can find the sample: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/